# Xpath extract text from a form

Tags: xpath

```
<td nowrap>Source name</td>
<td style="text-align: justify">Fresh postmortem eye<br>
```

I need to extract the text "Fresh postmortem eye" that comes after "Source name" on a form.   I tried this:

```
//Source name/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

and didn't get anything.  I'm hacking together a webscraper.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
//td[.="Source name"]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

Comment: @kxb35 , Did you try this solution? any feedback?