# Extract entire sibling element after element containing specific text

Tags: xpath, text, extract, siblings

```
<a href="/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GPL17021" onmouseout="onLinkOut('HelpMessage' , geo_empty_help)" onmouseover="onLinkOver('HelpMessage' , geoaxema_recenter)">GPL17021</a></td>
    <td valign="top">Illumina HiSeq 2500 (Mus musculus)</td>
```

I would like to extract "Illumina HiSeq 2500 (Mus Musculus)".  I used this XPath code:

```
//a[contains(., "GPL")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

The text follows a number that always contains "GPL".  I can select "GPL17021" but nothing shows up when I look for the first td after it.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML sample is not complete, but it seem that link is actually a child of `td`, so following `td` is not a *sibling*.

Try below to select required node:

```
//td[contains(a, "GPL")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
```

Comment: @kxb35 , did you try this solution? Any feedback?

Comment: @kxb35 , great! You can [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in case it solved your issue as well as [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949273/xpath-extract-text-from-a-form/52949664#52949664). Thanks